# How to move single layer element?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have several layers all within a group. When I click a text element with the move tool and try to drag it, everything within the group moves.

I can click the text layer and move it with the arrow keys but is there a way to drag just this text layer?

Comment: The move tool *should* move only the layer selected. Unless they're linked maybe (there'll be a little chain icon on the layers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably got your Move Tool set to move group rather than layer.

If you go to the top menu when the move tool is selected, check your drop down is set to Layer.

[image]

Or maybe your layers could be linked, usually indicated with a chain symbol on the layers/group